# A way to serialize an into an XML with attributes in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

When I call an api, I get an xml response like this.
I need to deserialize this into an object and then serialize it back to an xml of this same format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person version= "xyz">
    <properties>
        <name> John</name>
        <city>nyc</city>
    </properties>
</Person>
```

I am facing two challenges

1>The properties has a variable list. I need to serialize this into a Map<String,String>. (key:name->value:John, key:city->value:nyc, etc)

2>When I serialize the Person object back to XML how do I add `version= "xyz"` attribute?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JAXB, with `@XmlAnyElement` for support of elements with arbitrary names.

The following works natively with Java 8. For Java 7, the stream logic in `toString()` needs to be changed to regular `for` loop. For Java 9+, where JAXB was removed, a JAXB library is needed.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class Person {

    private String version;
    private List<Element> properties;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "properties")
    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Element> getProperties() {
        return this.properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<Element> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public void addProperty(String name, String value) {
        try {
            Element elem = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument().createElement(name);
            elem.setTextContent(value);
            if (this.properties == null)
                this.properties = new ArrayList<>();
            this.properties.add(elem);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String propertiesAsString = this.properties.stream()
                .map(e -> e.getLocalName() + ": \"" + e.getTextContent() + "\"")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
        return "Person[version=" + this.version + ", properties=" + propertiesAsString + "]";
    }

}
```

*Test*

```java
Person person = new Person();
person.setVersion("xyz");
person.addProperty("name", " John");
person.addProperty("city", "nyc");

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
StringWriter xml = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(person, xml);
System.out.println(xml);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Person person2 = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
System.out.println(person2);
```

*Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person version="xyz">
    <properties>
        <name> John</name>
        <city>nyc</city>
    </properties>
</Person>

Person[version=xyz, properties=[name: " John", city: "nyc"]]
```